# What would a River Shaman look like?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, shaman

What sort of build would be appropriate for a Shaman dedicated to a River Spirit? Or maybe an otter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 4th ed D&D I'd go with a Guardian Shaman Human with the Foamgather Heritage feat.  I went with guardian because it is the most defensive and healy which I think fits a water theme well.  The Dark Sun campaign book has an elemental spirit build option for the shaman which might work well too.  The foamgather feat is there for a water tribe feel without going water genasi.